# How to get an OpenGL Hello World working for OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I've been trying to compile a Hello World OpenGL application on OSX Lion. I have tried compilling the following file with `g++ main.cpp -o test -lglut`

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void displayMe(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(300, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello world :D");
    glutDisplayFunc(displayMe);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
   In file included from /usr/local/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:122:19: error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:123:20: error: GL/glu.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/local/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:439: error: variable or field ‘glutUseLayer’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:439: error: ‘GLenum’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:498: error: ‘GLenum’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:499: error: ‘GLenum’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:501: error: ‘GLenum’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:516: error: variable or field ‘glutWireCube’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:516: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:517: error: variable or field ‘glutSolidCube’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:517: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:518: error: variable or field ‘glutWireSphere’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:518: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:518: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:518: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:519: error: variable or field ‘glutSolidSphere’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:519: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:519: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:519: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:520: error: variable or field ‘glutWireCone’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:520: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:520: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:520: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:520: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:521: error: variable or field ‘glutSolidCone’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:521: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:521: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:521: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:521: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:523: error: variable or field ‘glutWireTorus’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:523: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:523: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:523: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:523: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:524: error: variable or field ‘glutSolidTorus’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:524: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:524: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:524: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:524: error: ‘GLint’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:537: error: variable or field ‘glutWireTeapot’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:537: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:538: error: variable or field ‘glutSolidTeapot’ declared void
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:538: error: ‘GLdouble’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:546: error: ‘GLenum’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:551: error: ‘GLenum’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:560: error: ‘GLfloat’ has not been declared
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:560: error: ‘GLfloat’ has not been declared
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:560: error: ‘GLfloat’ has not been declared
/usr/local/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:561: error: ‘GLfloat’ does not name a type
main.cpp: In function ‘void displayMe()’:
main.cpp:5: error: ‘GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:5: error: ‘glClear’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:6: error: ‘GL_POLYGON’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:6: error: ‘glBegin’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:7: error: ‘glVertex3f’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:11: error: ‘glEnd’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:12: error: ‘glFlush’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Notice how even the installed GL libs are failing to load their dependencies? Its not related to the project. Some extension you should have installed are borked or missing.

Comment: Yes. I don't know how I'm supposed to fix that, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866331/freeglut-on-mac-os-x-lion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X is a very non-standard platform. You have encountered one of those situations. In particular, instead of linking against the GL and GLUT libraries on OS X, you use the appropriate framework: `-framework OpenGL` and `-framework GLUT` instead of `-lGL` and `-lglut`

In your code, you should have something like this:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
# include <OpenGL/gl.h>
# include <OpenGL/glu.h>
# include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
# include <GL/gl.h>
# include <GL/glu.h>
# include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

Generally speaking you'll need a lot more `#ifdef __APPLE__` hacks to write code that works on OS X and other more standard platforms. But this should cover most of the bases for OS X. Also note that anything that uses *glew* or libraries like it should be completely pre-processed out on OS X; you (generally) don't load extensions at run-time on OS X.